# How to write c# appSettings with several (sub)sections

Tags: c#, winforms, appsettings

i have been checking around, trying to find a way to write to the exe.config-file.

I can read/write to  area just fine, but since we use 2 different DLL's from siemens to automate some stuff, i need to add a bunch of paths in a different section of the exe.config-file.

This is how the config should look like in the structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<appSettings>
    <add key="Siemens.Engineering.dll" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Siemens\Automation\Portal V13\PublicAPI\V13 SP1\Siemens.Engineering.dll" />
    <add key="Siemens.Engineering.Hmi.dll" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Siemens\Automation\Portal V13\PublicAPI\V13 SP1\Siemens.Engineering.Hmi.dll" />
    <add key="TempDirectory" value="D:\Scania Oskarshamn\Alarm_text" />
    <add key="AlarmTextPath" value="AlarmTexts" />
    <add key="Auto.Compile" value="True" />
    <add key="Auto.ExtractAlarms" value="True" />
    <add key="Auto.ImportAlarms" value="True" />
    <add key="Compile.HMI" value="changes" />
    <add key="Lang1" value="sv-SE:Swedish (Sweden)" />
    <add key="Lang2" value="en-GB:English (United Kingdom)" />
    <add key="Lang3" value="pt-BR:Portugese (Brazil)" />
    <add key="LangChecked" value="sv-SE:en-GB" />
</appSettings>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
</startup>

    <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Siemens.Engineering" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="d29ec89bac048f84"/>
            <codeBase version="1.2.0.0" href="FILE://C:\Program Files (x86)\Siemens\Automation\Portal V13\PublicAPI\V13 SP1\Siemens.Engineering.dll"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Siemens.Engineering.Hmi" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="37b6e3a80df0900f"/>
            <codeBase version="1.2.0.0" href="FILE://C:\Program Files (x86)\Siemens\Automation\Portal V13\PublicAPI\V13 SP1\Siemens.Engineering.Hmi.dll"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>  

</configuration>
```

I need to change the href part in the  tags, and if this section does not exist, i also need to add the whole structure below .
I just need to write these parts.

**EDIT: Now i dont even need the paths in the config, using registry to lookup path and use AssemblyResolve to make it work.
Solved this by using**:

```
        public frmAutomate(AutoData autoData)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AppDomain CurrentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(MyResolver);
}
        private static Assembly MyResolver(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            int index = args.Name.IndexOf(',');
            if (index == -1)
            {
                return null;
            }
            string name = args.Name.Substring(0, index) + ".dll";
            // Check for 64bit installation
            RegistryKey filePathReg = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Siemens\\Automation\\_InstalledSW\\TIAP13\\TIA_Opns");

            // Check for 32bit installation
            if (filePathReg == null)
                filePathReg = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Siemens\\Automation\\_InstalledSW\\TIAP13\\TIA_Opns");

            string filePath = filePathReg.GetValue("Path").ToString() + "PublicAPI\\V13 SP1";

            string path = Path.Combine(filePath, name);
            // User must provide the correct path
            string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(path);
            if (File.Exists(fullPath))
            {
                return Assembly.LoadFrom(fullPath);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: have you heard config transforms and slow-cheetah

Comment: Are you trying to change this as part of your release process? Or at runtime?

Comment: When the application starts, it should check the path of the DLL's and then write it, or when the path is changed in the application, so it will always be up to date (not that is should change more than once per computer)

Comment: Which parts should change? What's the input? What's the expected output? When do you need to change them (in CI pipeline or at run-time)?

Comment: @RezaAghaei: codeBase version="1.2.0.0" href="FILE://C:\Program Files (x86)\Siemens\Automation\Portal V13\PublicAPI\V13 SP1\Siemens.Engineering.dll"/ <-- The path after FILE://

Comment: Typically this is done during the build process. Apart an exceptional case, your .config file should not change during runtime.

Comment: @labilbe: This path is 100% dependant on the users installation path of the siemens software and cannot be determined at build process.

Comment: Ah, found another c# example for Siemens OpenNess and in there they check the registry for the path and uses
   AppDomain CurrentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
   CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(MyResolver);
To point to the DLL's.

Comment: Do the Siemens assemblies directly look at .config for the settings, or do you just want to store settings which you will read and pass to the assemblies? You can do that with a custom configuration section. It's an easy way to separate out a section of config values (unless the types are complex, then it can turn into an unholy nightmare.) But it's great for key value pairs. If that helps I can follow up with an example.